# AndroidManifest File not shown in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I just installed Android Studio in my machine and still exploring it but I have several problems my AndroidManifest file is look like this as shown in image.

[image: Image in encrypted form]

Comment: If you do not know what Gradle is, you really should not be working with Android Studio while it is in the early-access preview state, IMHO. Use IntelliJ IDEA, which has some Android integration and is the underpinnings of Android Studio.

Comment: sorry my bad i know what's gradle is but i forget to delete that line while posting my question. But Thank you.. IMHO

Comment: this looks like a heavy encoding issue. Where does your manifest comes from? Git? Subversion? Downloaded? Created?

Comment: This could also be the compiled version of the manifest that goes into the APK file.

Comment: apparently manifest file is in binary, if you downloaded it from somewhere or got it from a rpeo you should try again to get it

Comment: Looks like it has been packaged, you are looking at the wrong manifest file.